# Factorial recursivo y codigo ASCII Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursión, factorial

espero que me puedan ayudar tengo que realizar un programa que haga factorizacion y acepte string y los convierta a codigo ASCII.

```
def factorial(numero):
    if(numero == 0 or numero == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return numero * factorial(numero-1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        num = int(input("De que número quieres saber el factorial? "))
        if(num < 0):
            print("El número debe ser mayor o igual a 0")
        else:
            print("El factorial de",num,"es",factorial(num,ord))

    except:
        print("Se espera un número")
```

Se que la función ord detecta la conversion a codigo ASCII, lo eh tratado de varias maneras pero no llego a una solución.

Cualquier sugerencia o error me gustaría saberlo para poder mejorar
Muchas gracias y que tengan buen dia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def recur_factorial(n):
    if n ==0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return n*recur_factorial(n-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = input("De que número quieres saber el factorial? ")
    if not num.isdigit():
        num_ord = ord(num)
        print(f"El factorial de {num} (ASCII= {num_ord}) es {recur_factorial(num_ord)}")

    elif int(num) < 0:
        print("El número debe ser mayor o igual a 0")
    else:
        print(f"El factorial de {num} es {recur_factorial(int(num))}")
```

Primero, asumo que tu programa recibe números y strings. si se recibe un string lo debo convertir a ACSII y luego dar el numero factorial, es correcto?

Segundo, en tu Codigo usas `try/except` pero no veo que tipo de excepcion quieres detectar, la exception solo se presentara si el usuario coloca una letra o simbolo como valor.

En mi código uso recurrencia para calcular el factorial, con el caso excepcional de 0 evaluado al principio.
al inicio uso `isdigit()` para asegurarme que el usuario entro un numero de lo contrario transformo el valor entrado en su equivalente ASCII  y aplico factorial

Comment: Ya te entendi. a que te referias y vi mi error de logica. Muchas gracias